# Adding new columns to a table using php/sql

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to create a feature that allows me to add a new column to a table in my database using sql and php. I currently have a front end form, where the user can select what table they wish to alter and input boxes for adding a new column name. I also want to display the new version of the selected table (i.e. with the new column attached) My front and back end scripts look like this below.

sql10.html:

```
    <form action="sql10.php" method="post">
        <select id="category">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
              <option id="customer" value="customer">Customer Table</option>
              <option id="booking "value="booking">Booking Table</option>
              <option id="bookingline" value="bookingline">Order Table</option>
              <option id="package" value="package">Package Table</option>
        </select> 
        <br><br>

          Column Name: <input type="text" name="colname" placeholder="Insert New Column Name">
          <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"> <input type="reset" value="Clear">
```

sql.php:

```
<?php
                $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "######", "#####")
                    or die("Could not connect: " . mysqli_error($conn));
                print "Successful Connection!";
                mysqli_select_db($conn, '#####') or die ('db will not open' );
                print " You have connected to the Assignment 3 database.<br>";

                $category  = $_POST["category"];
                $newcolumn = $_POST["colname"];

                $query1="ALTER TABLE $category ADD $newcolumn varchar(255)";
                $query2 = "SELECT * FROM $category";
                mysqli_query($conn, $query1) or die ("Invalid query");
                echo "Success in database entry";

                $numrows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
                echo $numrows . "row updated<br>";

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("Invalid query");
                $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                    echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Booking ID</th></tr>";
                    for($i=0; $i<$num; $i++) { //uses $num as loop end value
                        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                        echo "<tr><td>" . $row[0] . "</td></tr>";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";

                mysqli_close($conn);
    ?>
```

As of using this code, I am not able to create a new column for tables. My database consists of multiple tables and I want the user to be able to select which table they wish to add a column to as well as enter the name of the new column. Can anybody see what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake is that your `select` tag doesn't have a `name` attribute. Remember that a form when is submitted, it takes the value of elements with the `name` attribute.

So, if you put in your HTML code `<select id="category" name="category">`, you will be able to catch its value in your `sql.php` query with `$_POST["category"]`; maybe the `$_POST["category"]` is arriving empty, and therefore you cannot execute the `$query1` sentence.

Comment: Tried that out but still having the same problem. Would I need name="category" within my options on my dropdown menu as well?

Comment: When I run the code it throws an error on line 28.. it doesn't seem to like me using $category = $_POST["category"];

Comment: You must have the `name` attribute in your HTML select. Try putting an `echo $category;` just after `$category  = $_POST["category"];` and an `echo $query1;` just after `$query1="ALTER TABLE $category ADD $newcolumn varchar(255)";`, and try to see if the variable is empty and how is the sql query being made.

Comment: I got it working! Thanks guys for you're help. I need to add AFTER the previous column name